# Recognize Matrix code from iPhone camera and translate it?

Tags: iphone, bitmap, camera

I would create an App that read this kind of code from the iPhone Camera and give me the alphanumerical code to verify its ticket...

[Ticket whit its code on the bottom](http://numeriingioco.myblog.it/media/01/01/1049104882.jpg)

What kind of code is this?
My friend suggest me to convert it into a bitmap image...and then?

Is there a method that take this code and return a int matrix whit 0 and 1 values?

Thank you!